# Why the binary file can't be created?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a program that in the main() function enters to a menu using a switch. In each case invoques another functions. In the function createFile(), which it is supposed to create a binary file, fill it out with 0's and then add the info that is required in the first space is returning (1) and it says that the file couldn't be created.  What am I doing wrong? What was my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct athletesInfo
{
    int heartRate;
    int time;
};

void createFile(fstream&);
void addInfo(fstream&);
void showInfo(fstream&);
int n;


int main(){
    int op;
    fstream fileA;
    
    do
    {
        cout<<"MENU"<<endl;
        cout<<"(1) Enter the first Heart Rate of an Athlete"<<endl;
        cout<<"(2) Add Another Athlete"<<endl;
        cout<<"(3) Show Info Athletes"<<endl;
        cout<<"(4) Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Choose an option: ";
        cin>>op;
        switch (op)
        {
            case 1:
                createFile(fileA);
                break;
            case 2:
                addInfo(fileA);
                break;
            case 3:
                showInfo(fileA);
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Choose a correct option."<<endl;
                break;
        }
    } while (op!=4);
    return 0;
}

void createFile(fstream &fileA){
    athletesInfo athle;

    fileA.open("athletes.dat", ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    if (fileA.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The file couldn't be created"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout<<"How many registers would you like?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fileA.seekg(i* sizeof(athletesInfo));
        athle.heartRate=0;
        athle.time= 0000;
        fileA.write((char *)&athle, sizeof(athletesInfo));
    }
    
    cout<<"Enter the info of the first athlete"<<endl;
    cout<<"Heart rate: ";
    cin>>athle.heartRate;
    cout<<"Time (00:00): ";
    cin>>athle.time;
    while (athle.heartRate<0 && athle.time>2359 && athle.time<0000)
    {
        cout<<"Wrong Inputs."<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter the info of the first athlete"<<endl;
        cout<<"Heart rate: ";
        cin>>athle.heartRate;
        cout<<"Time (00:00): ";
        cin>>athle.time;
    }

    fileA.write((char *)&athle, sizeof(athletesInfo));

    fileA.close();

}
void addInfo(fstream& fileAthletes){

};
void showInfo(fstream& fileAthletes){

};
```

Comment: Opening with `ios::in` requires that the file exists. It is also unclear how you expect to `seekg(i* sizeof(athletesInfo))` in an empty file, and why you want to have `n` zeroed entries before the one you enter data for.

Comment: Thank U, I appreciate your support! <3

Comment: Further, why you `ios::in` and `seekg` when you never read anything is another mystery. I would recommend reading more about how file streams work and then starting over.

Comment: `struct athletesInfo` -- FYI -- Currently, your `athletesInfo` contains only `int` types, thus making it compatible with "binary file reading/writing".  However, if you change your `athletesInfo` to include types that will make it non-trivially-copyable (like adding a `std::string` member), or if it will contain pointers, then the binary file code you have now (after making the changes suggested in the comments) will not work correctly.  Then you need to investigate how to propely serialize the type to the file.

Comment: Why do you keep seeking after writing to the file?  There is no need to seek, just keep writing; as the file pointer automatically advances to the next location (in the file).

Comment: Since the file is opened and then closed in the `createFile` function it's unclear why you are passing a file variable as a parameter. You don't need to use only one file variable, each function can declare it's own file variable. And each function can open the file in the way it needs to, the `createFile` function only needs to open the file for writing. This is what the actual problem is.